# How do I remove spaces in a string using a loop in python?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

```
def onlyLetters(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == " ":
           s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
           return s
        return s
```

Why is my above loop not working? It seems like it's only doing it once.

For example, if i have the string "**Hello how are you**", it's returning "**Hellohow are you**". I want it to check the string again and remove another space, and keep doing it until there are no spaces left. How do I fix this code?

Comment: How about `your_string.replace(' ', '')`?

Comment: Just remove `return s` from if condition.

Comment: Works for me if I remove the {return s} for the if condition

Comment: If I remove the first return s, it says "string index out of range"

Answer (score 4):

Your code is stopping after the first space is replaced because you've told it to. You have `return s` inside the loop, and when that is reached, the rest of the loop is abandoned since the function exits. You should remove that line entirely.

There's another issue though, related to how you're indexing. When you iterate on `range(len(s))` for your indexes, you're going to go to the length of the original string. If you've removed some spaces, however, those last few indexes will no longer be valid (since the modified string is shorter). Another similar issue will come up if there are two spaces in a row (as in `"foo  bar"`). Your code will only be able to replace the first one. After the first space is removed, the second spaces will move up and be at the same index, but the loop will move on to the next index without seeing it.

You can fix this in two different ways. The easiest fix is to loop over the indexes in reverse order. Removing a space towards the end won't change the indexes of the earlier spaces, and the numerically smallest indexes will always be valid even as the string shrinks.

```
def onlyLetters(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1): # loop in reverse order
        if s[i] == " ":
            s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
    return s
```

The other approach is to abandon the `for` loop for the indexes and use a `while` loop while manually updating the index variable:

```
def onlyLetters(s):
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] == " ":
            s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
        else:
            i += 1
    return s
```

Comment: after I remove the first return s, i get: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: and this: ----> 3         if s[i] == " ":

Comment: The `IndexError` should only occur if you're looping in a forward direction. If you loop in reverse you won't have that problem.

Comment: Oh wow, it worked! But I don't understand, why doesn't it work if I loop in the forward direction?

Comment: The exception happens because your string gets shorter each time you remove a space. If you're iterating forwards, you keep going to the last indexes that don't exist any more. When iterating in reverse, you end with the smallest indexes which are always valid.

Comment: I've updated to show another approach to solving the problem while iterating in a forwards direction using a `while` loop. The `while` loop can work because it checks `len(s)` after each replacement and only updates in index `i` when a non-space letter is seen.

Comment: sure my string gets shorter each time I remove a space but doesn't the "for i in range(len(s))" readjust it every time to account for that? And why do I keep going to the last indexes. What does that mean? Shouldn't I be going through the spaces in order? Btw thanks for posting the forward version.

Comment: what does `range(len(s)-1, -1, -1)` mean? I start at len(s)-1? stop at -1, and my step is -1? How can I stop at -1, when that is out of the range?

Comment: No, `range(len(s))` only evaluates `len(s)` once and then creates a `range` object from it (or a list of values if you're using Python 2). For the reversed range, the range stops just before reaching `-1`, just like `range(5)` stops just before reaching `5`.

Comment: okay it's clearer now, but I still don't see how going backwards fixes the problem of going to the last indexes. How does going backwards prevent indexes from disappearing? What do you mean by ending with the smallest index. Could you please show an example? Thanks, for all your help thus far

Comment: When iterating in reverse, the largest indexes are checked first, before any spaces have been removed. Even with a string that consists of entirely spaces, we can remove each character as we go from right to left, and each index we use is valid at the time we're using it (it becomes invalid afterwards, but that's OK since we don't use it again).

Comment: for example, going in reverse, if I start with "hello how are you" I should have 17 indexes, from 0 to 16, correct? Now after going through the first time, it will see the space between "are" and "you" right and return s = "hello how areyou" right? Now what happened to index 16? Did it disappear? Does this s not go back into len(s) in range to make a new range? If it didn't disappear, doesn't the function encounter a " " at index 16 where the "u" used to be?

Comment: That `"u"` character was in index 16 when we checked it as the first thing we did. We don't need to check it again after we've removed one of the spaces and it moves up to index 15, we're already at index 13 and we'll move on to index 12 next. The `range` and the indexes we're iterating on don't get recalculated as the string changes size.

Answer (score 2):

just use python replace() method for Strings.

```
s.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: I can't use s.replace, I need to do it without any functions like that, only looping

Comment: problem with your code is the return method inside the if condition. It stops execution of the method after processing the first space. Remove it and you will be good to go.

Comment: thanks, but it's still not working, I'm getting an error: "string index out of range"

Comment: Ok I understood the problem. Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all spaces, use str.replace():

```
sentence = ' Freeman was here'
sentence.replace(" ", "")
>>> 'Freemanwashere'
```

If you want to remove leading and ending spaces, use str.strip():

```
sentence = ' Freeman was here'
sentence.strip()
>>> 'Freeman was here'
```

If you want to remove duplicated spaces, use str.split():

```
sentence = ' Freeman was here'
" ".join(sentence.split())
>>> 'Freemanwashere'
```

If you also want to remove all the other strange whitespace characters that exist in unicode you can use re.sub with the re.UNICODE arguement:

```
text = re.sub(r"\s+", "", text, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

or something like this,it's handles any whitespace characters that you're not thinking of  :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '', 'Freeman was here')
'Freemanwashere'
```

if you don’t want to use anything like `replace()` or `join()` etc.  you can do this :

```
def filter(input):
    for i in input:
        yield " " if i in " ,.?!;:" else i

def expand(input):
    for i in input:
        yield None if i == " " else object(), i

def uniq(input):
    last = object()
    for key, i in input:
        if key == last:
            continue
        yield key, i

def compact(input):
    for key, i in input:
        yield i

yourText = compact(uniq(expand(filter(input()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell, because the indentation in your example is hard to understand. But it looks to me like after you encounter and remove the very first space, you are returning s. So you only get a chance to remove one space before returning.

Try only returning s once you are out of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `s.replace(" ", "")`. This will take all your spaces (`" "`) and replace it by nothing (`""`), effectively removing the spaces.

Comment: can't use s.replace. I need to do it without that

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the function after the first occurrence of a `","`, which means it exits the loop and the function altogether. That's why it's only working for the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own code only then try running this:

```
def onlyLetters(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == " ":
           s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
    return s
```

---

or better you may use:

```
def onlyLetters(s):
    return s.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: Your return statement in the second code sample seems to be in completely the wrong place ...

Comment: Not really... `str` are immutable so you want to `return s.replace(' ', '')`.

Comment: Well yes, you were correct. I made changes now. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def onlyLetters(s):
   length=len(s)
   i=0
   while(i<length):

      if s[i] == " ":
         s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
         length=len(s)
      else
         i+=1

   return s
```

Comment: This won't work correctly if there are two or more spaces in a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_spaces(text):
    text_with_out_spaces='';
    while text!='':
        next_character=text[0];
        if next_character!=' ':
            text_with_out_spaces=text_with_out_spaces +next_character;
        text=text[1:];
    return text_with_out_spaces

print remove_spaces("Hi Azzam !! ?");
```

[image: the output screenshot]